# Dynamic drawn background in CSS

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, background

I am currently trying to implement a drawn background as shown in this concept:
[image: website draft]

I am currently using bootstraps `container` class to center and align my content. How do I position some SVGs so that they are between the outer breakpoint and the side of the viewport? (as shown in the drawing)

I already found a solution with a sticky background image, as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50849747/sticky-background-image-w-css) post but that's not my goal. I am trying to maximize performance and use vector graphics (or mabye even canvas)

Comment: how far down is it supposed to go ? at one point the bg will be entirely black. Share your code with what you've done so far. and clarify what area is that bg supposed to cover . a single linear gradient will do that job actually.  `background:
    linear-gradient(75deg, #000 12.5%, #0000 12.6%, #0000 16%, #000 16.1%, #000 18%, #0000 18.1%,#0000 80%, #000 80.1%, #000 82%, #0000 82.1% , #0000 85%, #000 85.1%, #000 87%, #0000 87.1%, #0000 90%, #000 90.1%)}`

Comment: The background lines should stay fixed to the view so that they don't cross the content