# How to fit a sticky background image and prevent overflow in css?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to auto-resize a sticky background image to cover my entire `div` tag

**My code:**

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

#header {
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
}

#rest {
  height:1000px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
}

#background {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1591447/pexels-photo-1591447.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 500px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

#content {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="rest">
  <div id="content">
    <span>
           mt enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in vmpor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in v consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolor
        </span>
  </div>
  <div id="background"></div>
</div>
```

However, the text `content` overflows and the image doesn't cover the entire background. Is there some way to fix that and make the background fit in the given below orientation?

[image]

**Edit**
I had to modify the body `height:1000px` so that the effect of what I need is visible but is there anyway to do it via `height:100%`?

Comment: what was the issue with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66389903/8620333 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out!
The trick was in using `grid`, it took me a while but I created this master piece!

Reference link: [How to create a sticky background using css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66389903/how-to-create-a-sticky-background-using-css)

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}

#rest {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  background: blue;
}

#content {
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 0;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: yellow;
}

#sticky_back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;

  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1591447/pexels-photo-1591447.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="rest">
    <div id="sticky_back"></div>
    <div id="content">
      <span>
        psum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim vennostididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostididunt ut laborere magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut alnostididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostididunt ut laborere magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut alnostididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim e et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostididunt ut laborere magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitatio
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note**
The only flaw is that the content seems to overflow when the width is less than `206px`
try changing the width here: https://jsfiddle.net/xh264cvd/7/ 
but I guess this solution works in the long run, kudos!

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background: #1e1e1e;
  height: 80px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1591447/pexels-photo-1591447.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.container section {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
}

@media (max-width:800px) {
  .container {
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="container">
  <section>
    mt enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
    sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
    nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in vmpor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
    labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in v consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolor
  </section>
</div>
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1591447/pexels-photo-1591447.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.container section {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
}

@media (max-width:800px) {
  .container {
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section>
    mt enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
    sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
    nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in vmpor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
    labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in v consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolor
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Mahesh YL can you explain your changes as well for better understanding of the question's author ?

Comment: @Mahesh YL it's good but the header is missing and the background isn't sticky,
also on widening the view there is white space bellow it

Comment: Header is ok, but sticky background? Do you mean fixed background property?

Comment: @Mahesh YL thanks for adding the header but what I meant by sticky background was that the background appears/sticks to the screen after scrolling past the header and stays in the same view while scrolling (like a sticky is suppose to do)